# jquery & ajax getting data from php in wordpress . admin-ajax.php returns 400

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am working on an arbor.js graph. What I want is to send member id query it from php return member tree json to again to jquery script. then print the tree.
here is HTML form

```
<form action="" method="post" id="blm_get_tree_view_meta_ajax_form" >           
    <?php echo $dropdown_html; ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="blm_member_tree_response">
    <input type="hidden" name="blm_mem_tree_meta_nonce" value="<?php echo $blm_add_meta_nonce ?>" />
    <input id="<?php echo $this->plugin_name; ?>-treeview_mem_id"  type="hidden" name="<?php echo "blm"; ?>[memid]" value="">
    <p class="submit"><input type="button" name="get_tree" id="get_tree" class="button button-primary" value="GET TREE"></p>
</form>
```

And this is the jquery script

```
<script>

jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
"use strict";
    
    $('#get_tree').on('click',function(){
        var user_id = $('#binary-level-marketting-treeview_mem_id').val();

        //console.log(user_id);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: params.ajaxurl,
            data:{action:'blm_member_tree_response', user_id:user_id},
            success:function(data){
                if(data.status == 'ok') {
                    console.log(data.nodes);
                    (function ($) {
                    var Renderer = function (canvas) {
                                var canvas = $(canvas).get(0);
                                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                                var particleSystem;
                                var that = {
                                    // arbor.js rendering goes here.
                                    
                                    //....
                                    //...
                                }         
                                    // and renderer
                                    $(document).ready(function () {
                            
                                        var data = {
                                            nodes: data.nodes,
                                            edges: data.edges
                                        }
                                        var sys = arbor.ParticleSystem(700, 700, 0.5);
                                        sys.parameters({ gravity:true});
                                        sys.renderer = Renderer("#viewport");
                                        sys.graft(data);
                            
                                    });
                    });
})(this.jQuery);
```

php response function as

```php
public function getTreeGraphView() {
        
    if (isset($_POST['blm_mem_tree_meta_nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['blm_mem_tree_meta_nonce'], 'blm_get_tree_view_meta_form_nonce'))
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['user_id'])){
            $data = array();
                    
            $mtree = new MemberTree();
            $mtree->getMemberTree($_POST['user_id']);
            $nodes_ = $mtree->getNode();
            $edges_ = $mtree->getEdge();
            $parent_ = $mtree->getParent();
                    
            $data['nodes'] = $nodes_;
            $data['edges'] = $edges_;
                
            echo $data;
            die( '0' );
                
        }
        wp_die();

    } else {
        wp_die(__('Invalid nonce specified', $this->plugin_name) , __('Error', $this->plugin_name) , array(
            'response' => 403,
            'back_link' => 'admin.php?page=' . $this->plugin_name.'-product',

        ));
    }
}
```

ajax action

```php
$this->loader->add_action( 'admin_ajax_blm_member_tree_response', $plugin_admin, 'getTreeGraphView');
```

enqueue scripting and localization did as it is.

The process is 99% success but admin-aax.php returns 400 status code. with following response

and also 0 append to output. I pit wpdie() at end of the function

[image]

I cant solve the issue anymore. any expert here?

Comment: You called die twice, first is die( '0' ); and the second is wp_die(); these two functions have a similarity, output the message and terminate the script. You can remove die('0') and keep wp_die(); or you can replace wp_die() with exit;

Comment: @TommyPradana Thanks for the quick response. I did both ways you explained but the issue remains the same. :(

Comment: The hook name should be `wp_ajax_blm_member_tree_response` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_blm_member_tree_response` for logged out users.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thank you for your response. noprive is not used because this is admin dashboard plugin. but I found a solution by your answer. I used hook as 'admin_ajax_blm_member_tree_response'   . I change it to 'wp_ajax_nopriv_blm_member_tree_response'. now  400 gone. 403 arrives. this is the error   {"nodes":"{1268:{'color':'red', 'shape':'dot', 'alpha':1'}}","edges":"}"}Invalid nonce specified

Comment: getting into it. The problem is I am not passing the nonce variable in the ajax calling function.  add nonce variable -->  $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: params.ajaxurl,
            data:{action:'blm_member_tree_response', user_id:user_id, blm_mem_tree_meta_nonce:<?php echo "'".$blm_add_meta_nonce_tree . "'"; ?> }, And php response function return $data. use json_encode($data). now response output is correnct. ajax code is 200. but not enter success function . need to work still. if any expert there

Answer (score 0):

Change your `die( '0' );` to `exit;` and its work for you.

Better way to return json in wordpress is `wp_send_json( $data, 200 )`

read more here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/